# How does R handle closing of data base connections

Tags: r, database, rodbc, rjdbc

If I create a data base connection within a function, the connection objects gets destroyed when the function finished executing. Does this reliably close the data base connection, or would it better to to close it manually first?

**Why I need to know this:**

I am working on a package that creates data base connections on the fly with either RODBC or RJDBC as backend. I designed my function interfaces so that you can pass in either username and password, or a connection object. Usually, when I pass in a connection object I do not want the connection to be closed on the termination of the function, while when I pass in username and password I want it to be closed.

If I do not have to worry about open connections, it would simplify things a lot for me and also save me a lot of headaches.

**Answer & More:**

I markded Benjamin's answer as the answer since it gives good advice, though actually what I was looking for is more Marek's comment that (paraphrased:) **connections can be open after the connection object is destroyed and there is no way to access them from R any more.**

I ended up going for a solution that involves creating an R6 class and defining `finalize()` method that closes the connection (it's a more powerful than `on.exit()`), but that is beyond the scope of this Question.

Comment: I'm just struggling with `RJDBC` which does not close connection even when object was removed. You can close connection by `dbDisconnect(name)`, but there is no way (AFAIK) to close it when you lost handle (`dbListConnection` won't work).

Comment: Side note: I switch from `RODBC` to `odbc` (https://cran.r-project.org/package=odbc) I recommend to look on it.

Comment: A pity. Sadly, I have to use RJDBC :(. That would actually already answer my question more or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write a lot of functions that create ODBC connections when they are called.  My standard practice is:

```
conn <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(...)
on.exit(RODBC::odbcClose(conn))
```

By putting the creation of the object and the code for its closing next to each other, I know that the connection will be closed when the function is finished. Using `on.exit` has the added advantage of closing the connection even if the function stops on an error.

#### Edit:

In the problem as your edit has described it, I think the same pattern is relevant.  You need to declare `on.exit` in a manner that it only gets called if you don't provide the connection object.

```
db_function <- function(conn = NULL, uid, pwd){
  if (is.null(conn)){
    conn <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(...) # Build conn with uid and pwd
    on.exit(RODBC::odbcClose(conn))
  }
}
```

A trivial example to show by-passing `on.exit`

```
test_fun <- function(on_exit = FALSE){
  if (on_exit) on.exit(print("hello world"))

  "Look at me"
}

test_fun()

test_fun(TRUE)
```

Comment: This is indeed what I usually do, however, my current use case is a bit more complicated. I do not always want the connection to be closed on termination of the function. I added some clarifications to the initial question.